# NodeJs - Making 'GET' request conditionally in a while loop with request module

Tags: javascript, request

I am accessing an API endpoint that is a little iffy. About 70% of the time it sends back the correct JSON response, but a few times it will crap out and send an XML that says "values /values". I want to make a while loop what requests until it gets the correct response back. In my case, I am guaranteed to get back the correct response eventually, so that is why I am looping instead of figuring out why the endpoint is crapping out.

Here is my code:

```
var gotValidResponse = false;

while(!gotValidResponse){
    request(options, function(err, res, body){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }

        try{
            data = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(data);
            gotValidResponse = true;
        }catch(e){
            console.log('trying again');
        }
     });
}

processJSON(data);
```

Obviously the code above does not work, but hopefully it is showing what I am trying to do. Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Like this?

```
var myData = getStuff(options);

function getStuff(options){
    request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return
        }

        try {
            data = JSON.parse(body);
            return data;
        } catch (e) {
            return getStuff(options);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Well, definitely dont do this, ever. That `while` loop will send a LOT of requests before one actually comes back (since `request` is async and all) - what you should do is make a method that does the request, then in the response do the check, if it's not what you want, call the method again. This way, each request completes before another is fired. In your example, if the server goes down, it'll just request infinitely.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you look at my edit and tell me if that is what you mean?

Comment: You're doing an asynchronous request, you will not get the return value like you think you will. You need to use a callback or promise

Comment: As paul says, look at the promise api, or even implement your own! You are sending potentially hundreds of requests before you even get the first response from your sever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost got it right in your edit. What you need to do is keep calling the function until it returns what you want. Like this (my conditionals are merely illustrative):

```
var attemps = 1;
var fake = function(data, cb) {
    console.log('Attemp nº', attemps);

    if(attemps < 5) {
    attemps += 1;
    return fake(data, cb);
  } else {
    return cb(null, 'completed');
  }
}

fake('whatever', function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eysu2amp/

If you check the console, you will see that the fake function gets called 5 times and then returns the data. The recursive calling of the function keeps passing the same callback function.

Comment: What I was looking for. Thank you!